# Condition over Button action

Tags: java, android-studio, button

I have made a small app that consists of the following activies:

profile activity

find activity

search activity

result activity

Both profile and find activity have a button that once I click it, it opens the search activity.

The search activity gives some options and when I click at 
the desired option it opens the result activity.

My goal is as follows:

If I got to the result activity through profile activity, I had like to have a button that has some onClick listener and its text is "Add"

If I got to the result activity through find activity, I had like to have a button that had different onClick listener and its text is "I want it"

So far what I did is basically created the exact same classes and activities with different name that the only difference is the button however im sure there is a better way.

I thought maybe there is an option to change button id and each id will do different action

Any suggestion would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Send a tag using Intent Extras from profile or search activity. In Result activity, create `if()` or `switch()` condition based on the tag received. Assign names based on the tag and also `setTag(String)` to the button. Implement OnClickListener in your activity.

     `@Override
     public void onClick(View v) {...}`

Instead of creating condition based on `v.getId()`, create condition based on `v.getTag()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some intent data(like boolean or activity class name) from **profile->search->Result Activity** or from **find->search->Result Activity** on the same key and pass that data from 1st Activity to the last Activity.

This will help you to know whether you are coming from Profile Activity or Find Activity and based on that intent data you can easily put checks while clicking on the btn.

And you also can change the text of the btn based on it as soon as you enter inside the Result activity.

```
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        String comingFrom = getIntent().getStringExtra("COMING_FROM");

        if(comingFrom.equalsIgnoreCase("ProfileActivity")) {
            btn.setText("Add");
        } else {
            btn.setText("I want it");
        }

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(comingFrom.equalsIgnoreCase("ProfileActivity")) {
                    // your code
                } else {
                    // your code
                }
            }
        });
```